What is this stuff in my plant pot that looks like orange frogspawn?

Does anyone know what this stuff is in the bottom of my plant pot? I noticed it when I was pouring the excess water in it, because I accidentally waterlogged my cactus. It could be slime mould, but it looks like it is a clump of distinct eggs....
Although I can't see how eggs could get in this indoor cactus pot, unless they were previously there or they are insect eggs.

They look like eggs - most likely from a slug or snail, but too hard to denfinitively tell from just this image alone.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
